# Error Code: 1288. The target table cte of the DELETE is not updatable

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates, sql-delete

How can I remove duplicates from below table from clients table?

[image]

Below SELECT query is giving me correct results however delete query is giving error.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY id) AS row_num, id, first_name, last_name
    FROM clients
)
SELECT * FROM cte
```

But:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY id) AS row_num, id, first_name, last_name
    FROM clients
)
DELETE FROM cte
WHERE row_num > 1;
```

Gives error:

> Error Code: 1288. The target table cte of the DELETE is not updatable.

I would like to understand why I am getting above error (1288). Thanks.

Expected result:

[image]

Comment: What is the primary key of your table? MySQL does not support updatable CTEs, so you need to join back the CTE to the table, which requires a unique id on each row...

Comment: Make sense. ID is the primary key. However, duplicate data is added in table by mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer based on previous answer which I think this is a duplicate as well.

The answer would be to use a primary key or:

- create a new table based on the current one

```
create table clients_distinct like clients
```

- add only the unique ids

```
INSERT INTO clients_distinct 
    SELECT DISTINCT * FROM clients;
```

- drop the original table

```
drop table clients
```

- rename the table

```
rename table clients_distinct to clients
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/_DX0LWi0)